# Task.Factory Timing Out in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timeout, taskfactory

I've been scouring for info on timeout settings for asynchronous tasks but I can't find anything that doesn't involve wait().  Maybe I'm looking at this wrong.

I have an API call that may take 10 minutes to complete a file transfer.  I spawned a new thread so the user doesn't have to sit and watch this happen.  I added the database updates so I can tell what's going on.  The upload starts, a few minutes later... nothing.  The transfer is aborted, there is no exception thrown and no database update.  This must mean the thread is dropped, right?  How do I keep it alive longer?  Thanks for any help.

```
Sub up_load(s As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim uploadtask As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() begin_upload(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)

    lblmsg.Text = "Successfully initiated upload"
End Sub

Sub begin_upload()

    Dim request As New YouTubeRequest(settings)
    Dim vidupload As New Video()
    Dim cmdupdate As SqlCommand

    vidupload.Title = "My Big Test Movie"
    vidupload.Tags.Add(New MediaCategory("Nonprofit", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema))
    vidupload.Keywords = "church, jesus"
    vidupload.Description = "See the entire video"
    vidupload.YouTubeEntry.Private = False
    vidupload.YouTubeEntry.setYouTubeExtension("location", "Downers Grove, IL")
    vidupload.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = New MediaFileSource("c:\users\greg\test3.asf", "video/x-ms-wmv")

    'updates fine
    cmdupdate = New SqlCommand("Update transactions set name='upload started' where transactionid='18'", conHyperData)
    conHyperData.Open()
    cmdupdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conHyperData.Close()

    Try

        'very long running task +5 min
        Dim createdVideo As Video = request.Upload(vidupload)

        'never gets here 
        cmdupdate = New SqlCommand("Update transactions set name='upload finished' where transactionid='18'", conHyperData)
        conHyperData.Open()
        cmdupdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conHyperData.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

        'never thrown, transfer aborts
        cmdupdate = New SqlCommand("Update transactions set name=@name where transactionid='18'", conHyperData)
        cmdupdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "failed - " & ex.ToString)
        conHyperData.Open()
        cmdupdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conHyperData.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: No, threads don't get “dropped” just like that. There is something else going on, have you tried walking through your code in debugger? Are you sure the thread isn't still working or maybe deadlocked?

Comment: I don't know how to track that any further.  The request.Upload is executing, the upload starts.  The upload aborts, the error code is not executed, the success code is not executed.  If it doesn't fail or succeed, what does it do?  I know this does work with smaller files <10MB, but not larger <100MB.

Comment: It's possible that the code could “hang”, waiting on something that never happens. But that depends on how is `YouTubeRequest` implemented.

Comment: Does that mean it will never timeout?  It seems like if the thread is still alive it should give up on a YouTube response eventually and return the exception.  I have submitted this to Google and am awaiting their response.

Comment: I have no idea, that depends on the code of `YouTubeRequest`. Threads don't timeout, but web requests usually do.